# What is the role of the node level bridge in overlay networking?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to understand, what is the exact role of the node level bridge (kbr0/docker0)in case of Kubernetes overlay networking presented here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/ovs-networking.md
https://github.com/coreos/flannel#flannel

I understand how overlay networks work, in general. However, it is not clear for me why we need that node specific bridge? Is it only to provide a bridge for docker? Cannot OvS or Flannel directly handle the interfaces to the containers?
If I consider the analogy of VMs in a cloud and distributed switches, there is no node/host specific bridge between the distributed switch and the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node specific bridge is currently something required by Docker.

There has been some discussion in Docker's GitHub issues [8951](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8951) and [9983](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9983) about moving towards a more complete multi-host networking model.

Comment: Thank you! We had such guess, it is good to have the confirmation.